# Как сделать горизонтальный progress bar с отрицательным значением?

Tags: android

Возможно, в заголовке отчасти чушь, но нужно сделать прогресс бар с нулевым значением в центре бара. То есть бар полностью белый, к примеру, а когда процесс идет влево или вправо, то закрашивается только область, в которую прогресс пополз. Делал подобное с seek bar, чтобы в две стороны тягать можно было, но проект удалил и заново что-то не клеится. Может вечерний тупняк и пора спать, а может кто подскажет?

Comment: То есть, вы хотите чтобы это был именно `ProgressBar`, не `SeekBar`? И, выходит, вы хотите ему ставить например `setProgress(-100)` и будет заполнена вся левая половина, `setProgress(50)` - заполнена половина правой? Или лучше `setLeftProgress` и `setRightProgress` и передавать положительные значения? И ещё - будет ли возможность поставить 2 прогресса - чтобы и слева и справа было сколько-то

Comment: что-то делал такое, просто поставил в linearLayout 2 progressBar и один из них перевернул. Всё довольно банально. 
С SeekBar тоже получиться

Comment: Возможно вот эта либа подойдёт: https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar#sample-usage---range-seekbar

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei мсье знает толк в извращениях) вы же мне еще советовали подменять класс anim_vector для анимации :D